# Binding issue with WPF user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

Here's what I essentially want.
A `UserControl` with a `TextBlock` whose `Text` property is binded to the `Prop` property of the `UserControl`. (This is just a representation of my actual problem)

Below is a part of my `UserControl` (`ClientDetailsControl.xaml`)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Prop}" />
```

Next is the `ClientDetailsControl.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class ClientDetailsControl : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty PropProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Prop", typeof(String), typeof(ClientDetailsControl));
    public String Prop { get; set; }

    public ClientDetailsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Now, In my main WPF window(`NewOrder.xaml`) I am using this `UserControl` as

```
<userControl:ClientDetailsControl Prop="{Binding MyProp}" />
```

The `MyProp` property is declared as follows in the `NewOrder.xaml.cs`

```
public String MyProp { get { return "HELLO"; } }
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> BindingExpression path error: 'MyProp' property not found on 'object'
>   ''ClientDetailsControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=MyProp;
>   DataItem='ClientDetailsControl' (Name=''); target element is
>   'ClientDetailsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'Prop' (type
>   'String')

When I simply write

```
<userControl:ClientDetailsControl Prop="ABCD" />
```

It works. However, when I try to bind the `Prop` property of the `UserControl` to `MyProp` it doesnt work.

How do I make this work??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`RelativeSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) property like this:

```
<userControl:ClientDetailsControl 
  Prop="{Binding MyProp,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: This works. Only one question. Why does this have to be so complex? How do the default WPF controls enable data binding to their properties? I don't need to give any RelativeSource in case of the default WPF controls. Then what is different when I try this in a user control?

Comment: check this link for more details about RelativeSource :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx also this link:http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/yougerthen/relativesources-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is that binding paths are relative to the DataContext, not to the (parent) control.

This is why you can fix this by setting the RelativeSource; in that case the binding path uses the RelativeSource as the starting point of finding the property.

Another way to solve it is by naming the parent and setting the ElementName of the binding.

The MVVM way of doing this is adding a property to a ViewModel class, set the parent control's DataContext to an instance of the ViewModel and binding both the parent control and the client control to that property.