# WPF UserControl cannot bind outside at form

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have already bound it within itself, but I cant figure out what is wrong with form binding. I was checking different posts, but i cant get it still(

User Control XML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Lab7_KPZ.Controls.UnitBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Lab7_KPZ.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="177" d:DesignWidth="169" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Label x:Name="HPlabel" Content="{Binding _HP, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="169" Background="#FF35DC5B" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label x:Name="MPlabel" Content="{Binding _MP, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="169" Background="#FF0387E2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

User control CS:

```
  public partial class UnitBar : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _hp = "1000 / 1000";
        private string _mp = "400 / 400";
        private string _imgPath;

        public string _HP
        {
            get
            { 
                return (string)GetValue(HitP);
            }
            set
            {

                SetValue(HitP, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("_HP");
            }
        }
        public string _MP
        {
            get
            {
                return _mp;
            }
            set
            {
                _hp = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("_MP");
            }
        } 

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HitP = DependencyProperty.Register("_HP", typeof(string), typeof(UnitBar),
                               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, EmpNamePropertyChanged));
        static void EmpNamePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UnitBar x = (UnitBar)sender;
            x._HP = (string)e.NewValue;
        }
        public UnitBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this; 
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

main window xml:

```
<Window x:Class="Lab7_KPZ.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Lab7_KPZ"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Lab7_KPZ.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Name="mainGrid"> 
        <controls:UnitBar _HP="{Binding Path=HP, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay }"> </controls:UnitBar> 

        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,237,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=HP, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay }" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="52" />
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,192,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding  Path=SaveCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="205,20,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=HP, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource }"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>

main window cs:
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new MyView(); 
        } 
    }
```

my view for datacontext :

```
{
        private string _hp;
        private int _mp;
        private int i = 5;

        public string HP
        {
            get { return _hp; }
            set
            {
                _hp = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("HP");
            }
        }
        public string stringHP
        {
            get { return "100 / 100"; } 
        }
        public int MP
        {
            get { return _mp; }
            set {
                _mp++;
                OnPropertyChanged("MP");
                }
        }

        private ICommand _saveCommand;

        public ICommand SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_saveCommand == null)
                {
                    _saveCommand = new RelayCommand(
                        param => this.SaveObject(),
                        param => this.CanSave()
                    );
                }
                return _saveCommand;
            }
        }

        private bool CanSave()
        {
            // Verify command can be executed here
            return true;
        } 
        private void SaveObject()
        {
            // Save command execution logic 
        } 


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure your problem is the same but take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451083/binding-issue-with-wpf-user-control

Comment: @user2946329 changed it to `<controls:UnitBar _HP="{Binding Path=HP,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=local:MyView}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay }"> </controls:UnitBar> `, found that, at first it could not find cuz of unknown context, know it sees it, but does not help still

Comment: so, the thing is, that binding works for local element, but it doesn't for user control binding. I did smt wrong with decency property?

Comment: Please be more specific about what the code is doing now and what you want it to do instead. I will note that the `UnitBar._MP` property uses `_mp` in the getter, but `_hp` in the setter. That seems wrong. But without knowing what problem is the immediate concern, I can't say whether that apparent bug is in fact the cause of your problem.

Comment: I think more is less in this case - you probably don't need to quote all your code to get this answered. I'd suggest to stick to the relevant parts only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with your code.

a) You should never set the `DataContext` of a `UserControl` to itself if you want to bind to it from outside the control. Remove this from the `UserControl` declaration: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

b) Use a `RelativeSource Binding` from inside the `UserControl` to data bind to its own properties:

```
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="HPlabel" Content="{Binding _HP, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        AncestorType={local:UnitBar}}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" 
        Width="169" Background="#FF35DC5B" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    <Label x:Name="MPlabel" Content="{Binding _MP, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
        AncestorType={local:UnitBar}}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,154,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" 
        Width="169" Background="#FF0387E2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

This will enable you to data bind to the `UserControl` from outside the control.

c) Define your `DependencyProperty`s correctly (example taken from the [Custom Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358(v=vs.100).aspx) page on MSDN):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AquariumGraphicProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "AquariumGraphic",
  typeof(Uri),
  typeof(AquariumObject),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, 
      new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUriChanged)
  )
);
public Uri AquariumGraphic
{
  get { return (Uri)GetValue(AquariumGraphicProperty); }
  set { SetValue(AquariumGraphicProperty, value); }
}
```

Note the naming convention... the CLR property gets the normal property name and the `DependencyProperty` gets the *same* name, but with 'Property' appended to the end. It is very uncommon to use an underscore in the name of one of these properties. In your case, one of your `DependencyProperty`s would look something like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HitProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "Hit",
  typeof(string),
  typeof(UnitBar),
  new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, EmpNamePropertyChanged)
);
public string Hit
{
  get { return (string)GetValue(HitProperty); }
  set { SetValue(HitProperty, value); }
}
```

In XAML, we use the name of the CLR property to data bind to... in this case, the above code would become:

```
<Label x:Name="HPlabel" Content="{Binding Hit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={local:UnitBar}}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,131,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" 
    Width="169" Background="#FF35DC5B" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
```