# Dependency property get value returning null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a dependency property in a user control

```
    public List<Exclusion> SelectedExclusions
    {
        get { return (List<Exclusion>)GetValue(SelectedExclusionsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedExclusionsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedExclusionsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TimeSeriesChart.SelectedExclusions), typeof(List<Exclusion>), typeof(TimeSeriesChart), new PropertyMetadata(new List<Exclusion>()));
```

The list is populated on delete key down:

```
  protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.Key == Key.Delete)               
    {     
      this.SelectedExclusions.Add(this.Exclusions[this.Index]);
    }
  }                   
}
```

In the view model I new up a list & public property. A delete command is invoked from the setter:

```
private IList<Exclusion> selectedExclusionsToDelete = new List<Exclusion>();

 public IList<Exclusion> SelectedExclusionsToDelete
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedExclusionsToDelete;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedExclusionsToDelete = value;

            //Delete the selected exclusion 
            ExecuteDeleteSelectedExclusionsCommand();
            this.RaisePropertyChanged();                          
        }
    }
```

Finally, my xaml binding in the view:

```
SelectedExclusions="{Binding SelectedExclusionsToDelete, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

My problem is that at run time the `SelectedExclusions` dp getter returns null instead of a `List<Exclusion>` Is there something I'm missing here given that the PropertyMetadata value is of type `List<Exclusion>`?

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451083/binding-issue-with-wpf-user-control

Comment: Enable binding diagnostics and look if you find any hint https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/12/11/wpf-data-binding-debug/

Comment: Changed the List to an ObservableCollection & it is initialised, not sure why. However, the property setter in my viewmodel is not hit when I add items to the dependency property collection in the control...

Comment: Why would the property setter get hit when you add an item to the collection? It doesn't. It only gets hit when you set the property itself to a new collection. Try to change the type of the properties to ObservableCollection<Exclusion> and handle the CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection<Exclusion>.